# Pop Up "Zendesk Messaging Widget" After Certain Amount of Time

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

As we know that the zendesk Messaging Widget doesn't have proactive chat natively, after deep research I made this script to help anyone who wants the widget to pop a while after the website loads.

Hope it helps you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     zE(function(){
        zE('messenger', 'open');
    });
    //You can add more APIs on this line
  }, 10000); //time’s in milliseconds - 10 seconds = 100000
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     zE(function(){
        zE('messenger', 'open');
    });
    //You can add more APIs on this line
  }, 10000); //time’s in milliseconds - 10 seconds = 100000
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proactive messaging is supported since April: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/5540317327770-Announcing-Proactive-Messages-in-Messaging-

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34794659)